# Ionic image to a messaging application

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I need you to click on an image in my application made with Ionic, I will me the possibility to send it by Whatsapp or any other messaging application installed on my mobile.
Can anyone help me as I get?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should implements this cordova plugin:

[Social Sharing plugin for Android, iOS](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)

This plugin is supported also by ngCordova:

[$cordovaSocialSharing](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/)

Answer (score 0):

Use below link to for Social Sharing in IONIC

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Official plugin: [cordovaSocialSharing](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/)

Alternatively, you can use this plugin: [cordova-plugin-share](https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-plugin-share)

Cordova Plugin to open native "share" popup in Android and iOS

**Install**

In your phonegap/cordova project, type:

cordova plugins add https://github.com/markmarijnissen/cordova-plugin-share.git

**Usage**

`navigator.share(text,title,mimetype);`

text: Text to share, i.e. "Incredible plugin"

title: Title of popup, i.e. "Share this quote" (android only, default: "Share")

mimetype: Mimetype, i.e. "image/jpeg" (android only, default: "plain/text")